# REST Endpoint: why am I retrieving duplicates using paging?

Tags: rest, get, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to use a GET statement to retrieve one variable from all entries of a Rest-endpoint. It's the user_ID I'm retrieving. The response is a typical Json file. I only save the user_ID.

There are around 2 Million entries all in all. I have to use a token to authenticate and the token only lasts for 10 minutes. Therefore, I try to retrieve the data using pagination in order to renew the token each time, so each load lasts less than 10 minutes.

So it's like:
`HTTPS:Myrestendpoint.net?page=1&size=500000`

There should be only unique user_IDs. I'm running the code 4 times with different pages (1-4).

Somehow I get duplicates if I combine the four parts to one file and use a distinct statement to select all unique values.

My question would be: Can it be that pagination is choosing random entries?

Further, if not. Is there a possibility to check the rest endpoint for duplicate entries?
If I use a filter in my GET Statement to filter for a duplicate user_ID, I also only get one entry, which confuses me more.